# Amortized anlysis of dynamic stack

Tags: algorithm, math

Following is text snippet regarding amortized ananlysis of dynamic stack.

> If we are implementing stack as a dynamic array. Say that
>   inserting into the array costs 1, taking an element out of array costs
>   1, and the cost of resizing the array is the number of elements moved.
>   (Say that all other operations, like incrementing or decrementing
>   "top" are free). If we decide to double the size of the array when  we
>   resize. Now, in any sequence of "n" operations, the total cost for
>   resizing is 1 +2 + 4+8 +...+(2^i) (i.e, 2 to power of i) for some 2^i
>   < n ( if all operations are pushes then (2 ^i) will be largest power
>   of 2 less than n). The sum is atmost 2n - 1. Adding in the additional
>   cost of "n" for inserting/removing, we get a total cost < 3n, and our
>   amoritzed cost per operations is < 3.

My question is how author came to conclusion that sum is at most 2n -1. Request to help with example or proof.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is the sum of a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) :

```
SUM(q^k for k = 0 to n) = (q ^n+1 -1)/ (q-1)
```

then in your case you have :

```
SUM(2^k for k = 0 to i) = 2^(i+1) - 1
```

Then since 2^i < n

```
2^(i+1) < 2n
```

and

```
SUM(2^k for k = 0 to i) = 2^(i+1) - 1 < 2n - 1
```

Comment: for q=2 its even simpler if you write the numbers in binary: 1 + 10 + 100 + 1000 ..

Comment: @yi_H aha :D yep. that's a pretty elegant approach. But I think there are already too many answers for such a basic question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the sum:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^i
```

We can see this is the same as:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^i
```

Let's denote this sum as `S(i)`. Looking at the first few values, you may see a pattern:

```
S(0) = 2^0       = 1         = 1
S(1) = 2^0 + 2^1 = 1 + 2     = 3
S(2) = ...       = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7
S(3) = ...       = ...       = 15
S(4) = ...       = ...       = 31
```

We can see that they all seem to be one less than powers of 2. To be more exact: `S(i)` *seems* to equal `2^(i+1) - 1`. We can prove this by induction:

**Base case:**

```
S(0) = 2^(0+1) - 1
```

We can trivially see that the above statement is true.

**Inductive step:**

We know that:

```
S(i) = S(i-1) + 2^(i)
```

which is evident from the definition of the sum. Furthermore, if `S(i-1) = 2^(i) - 1` then:

```
S(i) = (2^(i) - 1) + 2^(i)
       = 2*(2^(i)) - 1
       = 2^(i+1) - 1
```

and therefore, we have proved that for all integer `i >= 0` that `S(i) = 2^(i+1) - 1`

Now, going back to your original question, we are given that `2^i < n`. We then have:

```
S(i) = 2^(i+1) - 1
     = 2*(2^i) - 1
     < 2*n - 1
```

and therefore, we have proven that S(i) < 2*n+1.